# AngularJS: Factory and Provider Scenarios

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I'm learning AngularJS and I noticed that A Factory is a short-hand for a Provider.
Can you tell me specific scenarios where I should/must use a Provider instead of a Factory? The codes stays much more readable if use a Factory method instead of the provider.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Provider is necessary when the provider itself has methods that you want the user of your service to call during the configuration phase of the application.

See for example the `$location` service: it has a `$locationProvider` which allows setting it to html5 mode, while the application is being configured (using `module.config()`).